# Quotation Marks in Python while Reading a CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am a total newbie in Python I must admit. I have a CSV file and now I have to write the values in a specific column in a sorted list, there are same values that repeats itself I also need to get rid of those.

So I have a column called reason and the index is as follows;

allow, school, 'business', education, school etc.
Only 'business' has apostrophes.

The output should be:

```
reasons=['allow', 'business', 'education','school']
```

I have written a code like this

```
import pandas as pd
df.head()
reasons=sorted(df["reason"].unique())
```

But the output of this is actually

```
reasons=[“'business'”,'allow','education','school']
```

So because business has already '' this apostrophe, in the output it shows it also with a quotation mark. Therefore places it also in the first line instead of the second.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there snippet of CSV file that is causing problems?

Comment: Is `reasons=[\`allow’, ’business’, ’education’, ‘school’]` supposed to represent a python list? Those two quote like things are not actually quotes and will raise a syntax error in python. One thing that makes this question hard to answer is that we don't know the context for any of these strings. Index is `allow, school, \`business’, education, school` ?? But none of those are python strings either. It seems likely that your original CSV is using the wrong characters for quoting (so you get the odd tick marks in "business"). Perhaps if you created a small example CSV file we could see?

Comment: It could be that a good CSV file was run through a document editor that switched the quoting and that ruined it.

Comment: Did you do `df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")`? If so, post a __small_ example CSV that demonstrates the problem. We need to know what quoting is used in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The sort order is not what we desire.

> because business has already ‘

To solve, simply edit the .CSV file, removing unwanted punctuation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I can not edit the .CSV file, as it is my homework and it was given so…